# Exception AdapterService ZF2

Tags: html, zend-framework2

Began studying zend framework 2, opened their tutorial and made according to the instructions but provides an exception:

An exception was raised while creating "Album \ Model \ AlbumTable"; no instance returned

```
return array (
     'db' => array (
         'driver' => 'Pdo',
         'dsn' => 'mysql: dbname = megashop; host = localhost;',
         'driver_options' => array (<br/>
             PDO :: MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \' UTF8 \ ''
         )
     )
     'service_manager' => array (
         'factories' => array (
              'Zend \ Db \ Adapter \ Adapter'
               => 'Zend \ Db \ Adapter \ AdapterServiceFactory',
          )
     )
);
```

user and password in local.php
in php.ini pdo connected

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the factory defined for the AlbumTable.  This kind of error usually means that a service was requested from the Service Locator, but it couldn't find a matching service to return.

You should probably have something similar to the below in your Module.php file.

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
       'factories' => array(
         'Album\Model\AlbumTable' => function($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $table = new AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
            return $table;
         },
       ),
     );
}
```

Which I took directly from the completed tutorial on GitHub:
https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial/blob/master/module/Album/Module.php